# PUT data from view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, put

I want to put data via controller for update.But I get this error:

```
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

I am using {{method_field('PUT')}}.Why I get this error?

route:

```
Route::post('updateColors/{color}', 'Admin\UserController@updateColor')->name('updateColors');
```

controller:

```
public function updateColor(Request $request, Color $color){...}
```

in view:

```
<form action="{{route('updateColors',$color)}}" method="POST">
.
.
.
@csrf
{{method_field('PUT')}}
</form>
```

Comment: ```Route::put('updateColors/{color}', 'Admin\UserController@updateColor')->name('updateColors');``` change your route method to put

Comment: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

Comment: as i told you change your route to  ```Route::put('/','/')``` in web.php file ,  or else remove ```{{method_field('PUT')}}``` from your blade file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@method('PUT')` in your form and a "Put route" in web.php `Route::put($uri, $callback);`